# Proper getopt usage

Tags: c, gnu, arguments

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html) there's an example on how to use GNU `getopt`. I understand most parts of the code but I have some questions:

1. Why is ctype lib included?

   I mean `unistd.h` is needed for `getopt`, `stdlib.h` is needed for `abort` and     `stdio.h` is the standard lib for `io`.
2. On the default case why do we use abort? cant' we just use return 1;?
3. I would like someone to share a link with more details on `optopt`, `optind` and `optarg` if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `ctype` is needed for `isprint()`
2. not sure - it might be slightly useful if you're not doing this in the `main` function, but printing an error then calling `exit(1)` is probably better; I guess this is just a minimal example, and one line was shorter than two
3. Here are several links you might find useful:

   - [FreeBSD man page for getopt(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getopt&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+9.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)
   - [Open Group UNIX Specification for getopt(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/getopt.html)

In brief:

`optopt`, `optind`, and `optarg` are external symbols.  They're global, and are declared in `unistd.h`.

`optopt` (`opt` = `option`) isn't usually needed.  It should be the same as the value returned by calling `getopt`.

`optarg` (`arg` = `argument`) is easy.  It's for the argument to a flag.  e.g. if `-f` is an option that requires a filename argument (`optstring` contains `f:`), you can do something like

```
    case 'f':
       filename = optarg;
       break;
```

`optind` (`ind` means `index`) tells you where option process finished after the end of your `while (flag = getopt...)` block.

e.g. before you add option handling, your script might look like this

```
// print command line arguments, start at 1 to skip the program name
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("arg[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

after adding your `getopt` block to handle options, you can do

```
// print command line arguments remaining after option processing
for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("arg[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

or

```
// skip command line options
argc -= optind; argv += optind;
// print command line arguments
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("arg[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

If you don't have any required command line arguments, then you don't have to worry about `optind`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! The 2 links you shared seem to have valuable info. Back to studying then. :)